# No author for subversion svn commits

Tags: svn, commit

I recently relocated my subversion repositories to a server on my local network and have an issue with it not recording the author of the person who committed a change.

On my computer I checkout a branch from the repository and can instantly start working on it and committing it without putting my SVN user/pass in (I use Tortoise SVN, so it must be cached in there I assume). With my checkout of my online server (that I've had for a while), whenever I commit, it records my username in the log, but not when I commit to my local server.

Is this a local setting on my local server or something? I've tried checking out user@path/to/branch, but committing from there still doesn't add my name to the log?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you enabled **full anonymous access** to repo (which, in common, is **A Bad Idea**), there is no need to identify user and, thus, nothing to write

Comment: Thanks, that was it! Never had to worry about it because none of the servers were accessible over the interwebs.

Comment: @Benno - blindly trust is a direct way to unexpected revelations. Just IMHO